# How to exclude header of Start-Transcript in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, logging, header

I want to output a log using Start-Transcript. But I don't want to include the log with the header. 
How do I remove the header of the output log?

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20191125095106
Username: \SYSTEM
RunAs User: \SYSTEM
Configuration Name: 
Machine: MININT-99N3MIH (Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0)
Host Application: X:\script.ps1
Process ID: 1996
PSVersion: 5.1.17763.134
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.17763.134
BuildVersion: 10.0.17763.134
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
```

I don't want to use this way `.\script.ps1 *> myscript.log`

Is there any idea how to remove the header?
Thank you for any advice, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PS 5, there is no `UseMinimalHeader` switch to the `Start-Transcript` cmdlet.
In this case, all you can do is to remove the header line ***Windows PowerShell transcript start*** after the log file has been created with something like this:

```
$log = 'D:\myscript.log'
(Get-Content -Path $log -Raw) -replace 'Windows PowerShell transcript start\s+' | Set-Content -Path $log -Force
```

Answer (score 3):

Headers and Footers are useful to separate multiple sessions, particularly in a single transcript.

However, if you are using PowerShell version 6.0+ you can make it slimmer by adding the parameter:

```
-UseMinimalHeader
```

For PS5, you can use "select -skip #" to remove the header. 
 For example `$log = get-content $yourfile -ReadCount 3 | select -skip 6 | Set-content $yourfile.`

The output should be starting from **"Transcript started, ..."**

Nevertheless, I still prefer to use a minimal header.

Comment: I don't use PS 6.0+, I use PS.5 this -UseMinimalHeader can not work in PS.5

Comment: I have revised my answer.

Comment: I am attempting to use this in a script, after the lines "Stop-Transcript" and "Start-sleep 10", but I still get the exception that the file is being used by another process. Have you had success getting that to work from the same script that is writing the transcript?

Comment: Hi Jacob, here is what I get "Stop-Transcript
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20240229091204" not quite sure what is the error message from your side. 
Perhaps check task manager if the file is in use.